# QGIS, Multiple lines and wrap on character?

Tags: qgis

How to make wrap on characters in Labeling layer settings.
I tried various solutions, but it works.
Does anyone know how to do?

Comment: Try inserting \n, that's the *new line* character in C and python.

Answer (score 5):

In the labels tab, find the `Formatting` section.  In there you have options for formatting multiple lines.  The first one is "`Wrap on character`".  This option allows you to specify a character(s) (no quotes) that Qgis will use as a new line character (i.e. it is not printed).

With a single field you might want to wrap on spaces (each new word on a new line).  In which case simply put a space in the 'Wrap on character' section.  It is as simple as that.

If you are concatenating two fields to make the label, I often insert a non alphanumeric character in the string to use as my wrap character e.g.:

***Label layer with***: "fielda" || '/' || "fieldb"
***Wrap on character***: / (no quotes - if you put quotes it will fail as it is then trying to wrap on the three character string of `"/"`).

You can of course insert '\n' between your fields when concatenating multiple fields and that works too (without identifying any character in the 'Wrap on character' field but using 'Wrap on character' gives you a little more control, especially where you have a single field.