# Creating multiple lines label in QGIS?

Tags: labeling, expression, qgis-2.12, string

I try to create a multiple lines label for this this polygon:

[image]

I red

[How to create multiline labels in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30084/how-to-create-multiline-labels-in-qgis)

[QGIS, Multiple lines and wrap on character?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109853/qgis-multiple-lines-and-wrap-on-character)

and tried to use the "wordwrap" function with this expression:

```
wordwrap('high sensivtity area - red',10  )
```

and in the output preview (down the Expression string builder) it look fine and this is the result i'm seeking - but when i choose OK - nothing change in the map.

I don't want to use the option to put a space in the 'Wrap on character' section, because i don't want each word i separate line

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 'high sensitivity area - red' is located in the attribute table you can use the field name instead of the direct string, as follows:

wordwrap(  "Field_name" ,10)

It should be defined in the expression under Label with:

[image]

Here is the output result:

[image]