# How to display(expression) specific multiline labels (8 labels only) with same field in QGIS?

Tags: labeling

I wanted to display the labels (which only 8 labels with the longer names)from one field. I've tried in multiple ways but wasn't works (NOT duplicated question)

I've tried this:
if  ("NAMEASCII"='Nikolajewsk na Armur', 'Nikolajewsk-\nna-Armur',NAMEASCII)

***[I've tried CASE statement, in my case works better only with IF statement]***

The result of this expression **(green: is the result, red: I need to do the same for this as well):**
[image]

Layer properties > Label > Rule: 
[image]

Label with:
[image]

**BUT** this is only one of them, there have 8 labels that I need to create the expression together (i don't know how to combine these 8 names only with one expression) just after the expression(above)
Can anyone tell me how? ***I may need a correct expression...*** because qgis giving me a syntax error, obviously, the expression that I created is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your initial attempt is invalid because you have no quotes around the 2nd `NAMEASCII". So it should be:

```
if( "NAMEASCII"='Nikolajewsk na Armur', 'Nikolajewsk-\nna-Armur',"NAMEASCII")
```

But a better solution might be something like:

```
if(  length( "NAMEASCII")>10,  wordwrap( "NAMEASCII", 10, '-'),"NAMEASCII")
```

where the wordwrap function

> Returns a string wrapped to a maximum/minimum number of characters.
>
> Syntax
>   wordwrap(string, wrap_length, delimiter_string)
>
> Arguments
>
> string
>   the string to be wrapped
>
> wrap_length
>   an integer. If wrap_length is positive the number represents the ideal maximum number of characters to wrap; if negative, the number represents the minimum number of characters to wrap.
>
> delimiter_string
>   the delimiter string to wrap to a new line (optional).

Comment: @Sigrid, @ JGH, @ Ian Turton, THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYS! Problem solved :)

Answer (score 5):

I can see you are working with rules (Regel). You can choose Formatting and choose wrap on character: '-'

Then add the '-' in your data for these 8 labels.
[image]

Comment: Hi, thx for replying, I've added one more screenshot which is the 'rules', I have 3 rules here, and I've tried to make another rule for only these 8 labels (created one column called "name_long"), but unfortunately it doesn't display on the map. YES, I did it like you've posted just now (on 'Wrap on character' box), but nothing changed.

Comment: These 8 populated places: Is it all there is in this layer, or do you have more populated places?

Comment: If you have more populated places and only want to show labels for these 8 places, you could add a field used for filtering the labels. Then I'd give these 8 places the same value.

Comment: These 8 of them are part populated places, and all these 8 in this layer. I need a correct combined expression for these 8 only, which will be filled in "Wrap on character" but not '-' (i think..)

Comment: @ Sigrid i want to show labels for all cities/ points, but these 8 has longer name than others, so the labels of all points need to be shown include these 8 which have longer name

Comment: ok. I see, that you want to show the - in the label (in order for the reader to know, that the word continues on next line). If you have access to change the data (I was assuming that before), then you can add another character. it could be / like in this answer [link] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109853/qgis-multiple-lines-and-wrap-on-character) .

Comment: If you do not have access to change the data, then I'm afraid I cannot help you beacuse I don't know how to write the expression.

Comment: @ Sigrid you've helped already, thx !

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using an `if` expression, you can use a `case`

```
CASE 
   WHEN "NAMEASCII"='Nikolajewsk na Armur' THEN 'Nikolajewsk-\nna-Armur'
   WHEN "NAMEASCII"='other name to modify' THEN 'A-B-C' 
   ELSE "NAMEASCII"
END
```

Alternatively, you can go to the `text` tab of the label, and check `Apply label text substitutes` at the bottom and click the `...` to the right. There, you can define the text to be changed.

[image: Label - text substitution]

[image: Label - text substitution - rules]